# Вывести пользователей которые отправили сообщение

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Таблица chat

```
id      from_id       to_id        message              time

1       1             3            Привет               05.01.2017 20:00
2       2             1            Здраствуй            05.01.2017 21:00
3       3             1            Привет!              05.01.2017 22:00
```

Таблица users

```
id     name
1      Алексей
2      Дмитрий
3      Ольга
```

Я хочу вывести в личном кабинете **Алексея** подобие:

```
3 Ольга: Послднее сообщение 05.01.2017 22:00
2 Дмитрий: Послднее сообщение 05.01.2017 21:00
```

> От больных которые тупо минусуют вопрос, толку нету..

Сам разобрался:

```
SELECT DISTINCT to, MAX(time) 
FROM CHAT where from = '"1"'
GROUP BY to 
ORDER BY MAX(time) DESC)
```

Получаем новые сообщении список без повторении дале уже можно будет вывести с именами.

Вот так выглядет личные сообщении Алексая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если последнее сообщение в чате с Ольгой написано Алексеем? А если с неким Иваном (id=4) этот Алексей не чатился? А если это страница Идиосинкразия, который вообще ненавидит чаты и никогда не отвечает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень сложно догадаться, что Вам нужно, но если Вы хотите для владельца личного кабинета получить список последних сообщений, которые ему адресованы, то вот SQL, который будет для Вас стартовой точкой:

```
SELECT [user_from].[id]
  ,[user_from].name
  ,' последнее сообщение '
  ,[time]
 FROM [chat], [users] user_to, [users] user_from
  where [chat].[to_id] = [user_to].[id] AND user_to.name = 'Алексей'
   AND [chat].[from_id] = [user_from].[id]
   AND [time] = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM [chat] chat1   WHERE chat1.from_id = chat.from_id);
```

Этот запрос будет выполняться в любой базе данных с поддержкой стандартного SQL. Если, что не понятно - спросите. На всякий случай полезная ссылка http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php

Comment: Если Вы "минусуете" ответ, то было бы логично указывать причину, как мне кажется

Comment: Могу предположить, что минус поставлен за то, что к вопросу приложен тег mysql, а у Вас квотирование имён как для Access/MS SQL

Comment: Прежде, чем выкладывать решение, его нужно проверить, а у меня во время праздников доступен только MS SQL. Я сознательно в запросе использовал, только то что есть во всех диалектах SQL, чтобы был ясен принцип. Очевидно, что этому запросу можно придать более современный вид, но это уже "рюшечки".